# Редирект через htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Есть 2 домена ab.ru и ab2.ru и они привязаны к одним и тем же файлам сайта. Как правильно прописать правильно, чтобы все страницы вида
ab2.ru/one редиректились на ab.ru ? Сейчас прописано так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ab2\.ru
RewriteRule (.*) http://ab.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы `ab2.ru/one` редиректилось, дополните правило вот так:

```
RewriteRule ^one/(.*) http://ab.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Есть 2 домена ab.ru и ab2.ru и они привязаны к одним и тем же файлам
>   сайта

Если они "привязаны", те являются алиасами, то ничего делать не нужно. ВП сам всё сделает (если адреса в его настройках указаны правильно)